# can a faulty ps2 mouse port cause my left click not register?

Tags: windows-10, mouse, troubleshooting, ps2

I'm using a **PS/2 mouse** and sometimes the mouse just stops working. So I would unplug and plug it in again and it would start working. After searching for a solution for my mouse click that stopped working after one of these times found out that apparently **unplugging and replugging** is a no no. Oops.

My question is have I messed up my PS/2 ports and so my left click is not registering? can something like that even happen or is it just my mouse that's the problem and I'm overthinking things at 5 in the morning? I really hope it's just the mouse.

Comment: no ... the same data line carries info about the other buttons and about the mouse movement ... faulty PS/2 port can cause the whole mouse to fail

Comment: i'm so freaking relived man. i can just pass the mouse to my father to fix it when he get's up.  phew. thanks for the answer.